# Java 8 Stream utilities for input data

Tags: java, parsing, java-8, java-stream

Imagine having some sort of incoming data either by callback or an `InputStream` that you need to **continuously** convert into a Java 8 `Stream`. We don't know when the incoming data-stream stops, but we know that it *can* stop.

So far I've seen two ways of getting around this problem and I'm interested in the best practices on how to achieve this. Mainly because I this must be something someone has faced before. There must be a simpler way of doing it than the ideas below.

1) The most simple way is to treat the source as a `Supplier` and just use `Stream.generate` to serve data:

```
Stream.generate(() -> blockCallToGetData());
```

However, this has the disadvantage, that the stream never ends. So whenever an input source stops sending, the stream just keeps calling the method. Unless we throw a Runtime exception naturally, but this can get ugly fast.

2) The second idea is to use a `Iterator` (converted to a `Spliterator`) where the `next` method blocks until we find the next element. As a crude example:

```
class BlockingIterator implements Iterator<Data> {

  @Override void boolean hasNext() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override Data next() {
    return blockCallToGetData();
  }

}
```

The advantage of this is that I can stop the stream by returning `false` in the `hasNext` method. However, in situations where we do not control the speed of the incoming data (such as in a callback), we would need to keep a buffer of ready elements for the iterator. This buffer could grow infinitely big, before someone calls `next` on the iterator.

So, my question goes; what is the best practice for serving blocking input into a stream?

Comment: I think the issue you describe for the iterator is shared by the supplier-based approach. If you can't control the speed of incoming data, and the data won't stop coming when you don't read it, then you must buffer it. Note that this is *not* the case with any I/O source that I know of. I/O sources always block waiting for the receiving end to acknowledge receipt.

Comment: Furthermore, if you have an asynchronous data source, then you would be better off handling it with an asynchronous API such as RxJava.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question contains a questionable assumption: that there *is* a good practice for serving blocking input into a stream.  Stream is not a reactive framework; while you can wedge it into being one with a big crowbar, the problems will likely pop out elsewhere as a result.  (The EG considered these use cases and concluded that we were better off providing something that does a complete job at one problem rather than a half job at two.)

If you need a reactive framework, the best practice is to use one.  RxJava is great.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is admittedly a hard question, but considering my requirements I went with the second solution. The question about overflowing buffers can be handled elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In [simple-react](https://github.com/aol/simple-react) we solved this problem by using (simple-react) [async Queues](https://github.com/aol/simple-react/wiki/Queues-explained) (an async wrapper over JDK Queue data-structures) that JDK Streams could read from. If the Queue is closed, the Stream will automatically disconnect.

The fast producer / slow consumer problem can be solved by the Queues. If the (simple-react) async Queue is backed by a bounded Blocking Queue, it will automatically slow down (block) any producing threads once the Queue gets full.

In contrast, the LazyFutureStream stream implementation uses non-blocking Queues internally and will even attempt to turn itself from consumer of data from the Queue, to a producer, if there is no data present (and as such it can operate as an entirely non-blocking Stream)

Example Using [PushableStreamBuilder](https://github.com/aol/simple-react/wiki/PushableStreamBuilder) :

```
 PushableLazyFutureStream<Integer> pushable = new PushableStreamBuilder()
            .withBackPressureAfter(100)
            .withBackPressureOn(true)
            .pushableLazyFutureStream();

    // pushable.getInput().fromStream(input); would also be acceptable to add input data
    pushable.getInput().add(100); 
    pushable.getInput().close();

    List list = pushable.getStream().collect(Collectors.toList());

     //list is [100]
```