# Java 8 lambda api

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm working to migrate from Rx Java to Java 8 lambdas.  One example I can't find is a way to buffer requests.  For example, in Rx Java, I can say the following.

```
Observable.create(getIterator()).buffer(20, 1000, TimeUnit. MILLISECONDS).doOnNext(list -> doWrite(list));
```

Where we buffer 20 elements into a list, or timeout at 1000 milliseconds, which ever happens first.

Observables in RX are a "push" style observable, where as Streams use a java pull.  Would this be possible implementing my own map operation in streams, or does the inability to emit cause problems with this since the `doOnNext` has to poll the previous element?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944784/java-8-stream-utilities-for-input-data/27950637#27950637

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to use a BlockingQueue and Guava. Using `Queues.drain`, you can create a `Collection` that you could then call `stream()` on and do your transformations. Here's a link: [Guava Queues.drain](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Queues.html#drain(java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue,%20java.util.Collection,%20int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

And here's a quick example:

```
public void transform(BlockingQueue<Something> input) 
{
    List<Something> buffer = new ArrayList<>(20);
    Queues.drain(input, buffer, 20, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    doWrite(buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[simple-react](https://github.com/aol/simple-react) has similar operators, but not this exact one. It's pretty extensible though, so it should be possible to write your own. With the caveat that I haven't written this in an IDE or tested it, roughly a buffer by size with timeout operator for simple-react would look something like this

```
  import com.aol.simple.react.async.Queue;
  import com.aol.simple.react.stream.traits.LazyFutureStream;
  import com.aol.simple.react.async.Queue.ClosedQueueException;
  import com.aol.simple.react.util.SimpleTimer;
  import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

  static LazyFutureStream batchBySizeAndTime(LazyFutureStream stream,int size,long time, TimeUnit unit) { 
    Queue queue = stream.toQueue();
    Function<Supplier<U>, Supplier<Collection<U>>> fn = s -> {
        return () -> {
            SimpleTimer timer = new SimpleTimer();
            List<U> list = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                do {
                    if(list.size()==size())
                        return list;
                    list.add(s.get());
                } while (timer.getElapsedNanoseconds()<unit.toNanos(time));
            } catch (ClosedQueueException e) {

                throw new ClosedQueueException(list);
            }
            return list;
        };
    };
    return stream.fromStream(queue.streamBatch(stream.getSubscription(), fn));
}
```